# Applying CSS box-shadow to shape within an SVG rather than the rectangular SVG canvas

Tags: css, svg

I have drawn a hexagon and exported it as an SVG.

After embedding in my page, I added a `box-shadow` in CSS.

However, the shadow is added to the rectangular canvas surrounding the hexagon, rather than the hexagon itself.

Until the shadow is added, the canvas is invisible due to having a transparent background.

How can I edit the SVG file such that the shadow is applied to the hexagon?

Comment: check `drop-shadow` instead

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. :)